# Stop Monitoring SQL Services for Registered Servers in SMSS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Question: Is it possible to stop SSMS from monitoring the service status of registered servers?

Details:
SSMS 2008 monitors the service status of every registered server.  From what I have seen it seems to reach out to every registered server every minute or so to check it's status, in my case that is over 100 servers.  This process has raised issues with our Security and Network departments.  Network identified it initially as suspicious traffic due to the fact that it appeard as an unknown utility was scanning the network for SQL Servers.  Security was concerned because the Security Event Logs on each server are being filled up with my logon events.

I have looked all over for a setting but can't seem to find one.  Am I missing it somewhere?

TIA,
Brian

Comment: I switched to my "Registered Servers" tab, and I see what you mean - as soon as I load the tab, it starts to work its way down the list, checking the status of every server. I usually don't use this tab - I know it's less than ideal, but if you just stick to the "Object Explorer" tab and connect to servers as you need them, you should avoid these status checks on all but the servers you're actively connected to. That's odd that you can't raise the interval of these checks, though.

Comment: You are correct, if I don't use the Registered Servers then the status checks don't happen.  In my case this isn't ideal...with approx 100 servers/instances, some using Windows Auth and others using SQL Auth, it becomes a real pain to go and lookup the necessary ID's/passwords and even server names at times, especially when paged in the middle of the night. I use the registered servers because in addition to logon info you can store a description and a custom color for the status bar for queries (ie Red = Prod, Yellow = QA, Green = Dev). I'm still looking and haven't found an answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer!!

While it is not possible (at least that I've found) to stop SSMS from checking the service status of registered servers it is possible to change the interval at which it checks it.

The short version is to create the following registry keys (DWORD):

(SQL Server 2008)
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell | PollingInterval = 600 (decimal)

(SQL Server 2005)
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell | PollingInterval = 600 (decimal)

This will make SSMS connect automatically every minute instead of every few seconds.

See this [MS Connect Post](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=247367) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't appear that there's any way to stop these status checks by SSMS, can you focus on helping them to see their harmlessness?

1. Can the network group allow certain exceptions to this particular rule (pinging servers on port 1433) in their scanning software, which would allow you and your group to monitor SQL Server uptime? Even if you weren't using SSMS, this type of sweeping monitoring activity is pretty common, and you'll know the requests will only ever come from a handful of workstations.
2. I don't think these SQL status checks generate any more events in the security log than any other activity, so maybe they were just concerned because it was something they weren't expecting. Could the security group be convinced that these events aren't dangerous, again as long as they're coming from certain approved workstations?

If neither of these is an option (or even if it is), you could help mitigate the problem by not connecting to all your SQL servers at once. Maybe just connect to the ones you need at the time - it looks like loading the entire list actively connects to each of them, but just connecting to the ones you intend to use in that session might help reduce the number of network sessions open.

I hope this helps - if it doesn't, or you've got some additional input that might help find a workaround, please post it!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We've already done #1 and the issue with the event log isn't that the entries are there it's that there are about 1000+ a day.
I'm not connecting to all my servers at once. I have entries for them in Registered Servers, basically shortcuts to connect with all settings saved. I usually only connect to a few at a time and close the connections when I am not using them.